# How to Join Array by preserving type of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
[866587, 9305, null, "867583/867523"]
```

Would like to convert to

```
(866587, 9305, null, '867583/867523')
```

Tried

```
`(${arr.reduce((a, elm) => a + (a ? ',' : '') + elm)})`
```

but it is converting all as integer

```
(866587, 9305, null, 867583/867523)
```

Comment: What is `(866587, 9305, null, '867583/867523')` supposed to mean? The `[ ]` are not *part* of the array; it's syntax for creating an array.

Comment: Array values i need to convert to make postgress multi update queries which accepts (xx,xx,xx) this format

Comment: pg-format %s s removing null and undefined value and %L is converting all values to string.

Comment: If this is for a PostgreSQL query, then I think you approach this the wrong way in the first place. You should use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to format your array as a stringified tuple, you will need to check a few things:

```js
const formatAsTuple = (arr) =>
  `(${arr.map((item) => {
    if (typeof item === 'string') return `'${item}'`;
    return `${item}`;
  }).join(', ')})`;

console.log(formatAsTuple([866587, 9305, null, "867583/867523"]));

console.log(formatAsTuple([null, undefined, 0, 1, false, true, 'x']));
```

This can be further simplified to:

```js
const formatAsTuple = (arr) => `(${
  arr
    .map((item) => typeof item === 'string' ? `'${item}'` : `${item}`)
    .join(', ')
})`;
```